# ruby regex: replace noun clusters in POS tagged data

Tags: ruby, regex, substitution

I have POS tagged English phrases of the form: `the_DT flower_NN pot_NN` and want to combine all noun sequences into a single noun separated by an underscore: `the_DT flower_pot_NN`.

I'm trying the following:

```
s.gsub!(/ ([^ ]+)_NN ([^ ]+)_NN/, " #{$1}_#{$2}_NN")
```

This solution fails when there are multiple nouns in a row such as: `the_DT monster_NN truck_NN wallpaper_NN`, which should become `the_DT monster_truck_wallpaper_NN`.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you want the output in your example to be `the_DT monster_truck_wallpaper_NN`?

Comment: Yes: `the_DT monster_NN truck_NN wallpaper_NN` should be: `the_DT monster_truck_wallpaper_NN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while s.gsub!(/\b(\S+)_NN\s+(\S+)_NN\b/, '\1_\2_NN')
end
```

You cannot do it all at once in a regexp, since there is no provision for recursion (or iteration). What you do is, join the adjacent pairs, then repeat until there are no adjacent NNs.

EDIT: Fixed the replacement part as well. Should work now.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The `$1` and `$2` seem to get clobbered.

Comment: if `x = the_DT monster_NN truck_NN wallpaper_NN` then `while x.gsub!(/\b([^ ]+)_NN\s+([^ ]+)_NN/, " #{$1}_#{$2}_NN"); end` yields `the_DT   monster_truck_NN`

Comment: Heh, sorry about that, didn't check the original expression for correctness first. Still, the essence of the answer is the unchanged: a `while` loop.

Comment: You actually can do it all at once with a positive lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this, using one global replace.

```
s.gsub!(/_NN\s+(?=\b[^ ]+_NN)/, "_");
```